# Ionic 5, Vue 3 - How to use Ionic lifecycle hooks inside setup()?

Tags: vue.js, ionic5, vuejs3

The `Ionic` documentation describes how to use the Ionic lifecycle methods like `ionViewWillEnter`, `ionViewDidEnter` etc. inside Vue `method`.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/lifecycle

I'm looking for a way to access them inside the new Vue 3 `setup()` method so that I can able to access the properties defined there. Is it something possible?

```
export default defineComponent({
   ...
   setup(){
      const list = ref([]);

      // I need something like this
      const ionViewDidEnter = () => {
         list.value.push(...['some', 'array', 'here']);
      },

      return {
         list,
         ionViewDidEnter
      };
   }
});
```

Comment: I suggest you use one of standard vue lifecycle methods until the ionic release is fully baked, the ionic lifecycle events are syntactic sugar on top of the vue events

Comment: @AaronSaunders, good thought, but none of the vue events works the same as ionViewWillEnter or ionViewDidEnter with respect to tabs workflow.

Comment: then listen to the tab events, there are listeners whenever the tabs change.. if you can be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish it makes it easier to answer... you just now mention tabs and it is not mentioned in the initial question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible in a composition API style since this PR was merged

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/pull/22970

```js
export default defineComponent({
  ...,
  components: { IonPage },
  setup() {
    onIonViewDidEnter(() => {
      console.log('ionViewDidEnter!');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, at least not yet, since the code firing the events is specifically looking for the lifecycle events to be registered as part of the component methods. Luckily I've submitted a PR which is going to fix this and allow you to define them the same way you would define mounted or any other Vue hooks.

I will make sure to add tests that cover the composition API scenario as well.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/pull/22241

Meaning that you'd be able to do it this way:

```js
export default defineComponent({
   ...
   ionViewDidEnter() {
     ...
   },
   setup(){
     ...
   }
});
```

Comment: How do I exactly call the ionic lifecycle hooks in setup now that the PR is merged? The official documentation doesn't say much about it...

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to what Mark Beech said, you will have to import `onIonViewDidEnter`

```
import { onIonViewDidEnter } from '@ionic/vue';

export default defineComponent({
   ...
   ionViewDidEnter() {
      console.log('Hompage');
   },
   setup(){
     ...
   }
});
```